# How can i output the hive query time to a file?

Tags: hive

I'm doing a `hive` performance test, and I want to output the query result
like this:

[image]

Comment: query result and query time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time taken is a STDERR output

if you use redirection result to a file " > x.log " to save result, add " 2>&1 " to redirect STDERR to STDOUT .